# Using Google maps with HTML geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, google-maps

I'm using geolocation to get a users current location. The problem is sometimes it doesn't return the accurate location. I want to then allow the user manually set the marker on the correct location on google map and then return the longitude and latitude of this new location.

Please any ideas?

This is the code i use in returning users location using geolocation

```
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} 
else { 
    document.getElementById("location-x").innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

function showPosition(position) {
var latitude= position.coords.latitude;
var longitude= position.coords.longitude;
document.getElementById("location-x").innerHTML = "Latitude: " + latitude + 
"<br>Longitude: " + longitude;
$("#latitude").val(latitude);
$("#longitude").val(longitude);
 var uluru = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};
 $("#map").show();
 var map = new google.maps.Map(
  document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 15, center: uluru});

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out you can set "draggable:true",

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map,draggable:true});
```

And the get current position of the marker by adding event listeners to the marker

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(evt){
document.getElementById('location-x').innerHTML = 'Latitude: ' 
+ evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + ' Longitude: ' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3);
});

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(evt){
document.getElementById('location-x').innerHTML = 'Getting new location...';
});
```

I hope this helps someone. Cheers